# Automatic Image Inpainting with Keras and GpuElemwise Errors

Tags: python, machine-learning, theano, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a Keras Model =>

> Input : Gray Image : (1, 224, 224)
>
> Output : RGB Image: (3, 224, 224)

and I want to predict pixel colors by giving it Grayscale images and getting RGB ones.
I tried to make a network in Keras which mostly resembles [this one (which has been made in Tensorflow)](http://tinyclouds.org/colorize).

Here's the Model code :

```
first_input = Input(batch_shape=(None, 1, 224, 224))

conv0_1_3 = Convolution2D(3, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv0_1_3', border_mode='same')(first_input)

conv1_1_64 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv1_1', border_mode='same')(conv0_1_3)
conv1_2_64 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv1_2', border_mode='same')(conv1_1_64)
conv1_2_64 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv1_2_64)

conv2_1_128 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv2_1', border_mode='same')(conv1_2_64)
conv2_2_128 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv2_2', border_mode='same')(conv2_1_128)
conv2_2_128 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv2_2_128)

conv3_1_256 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv3_1', border_mode='same')(conv2_2_128)
conv3_2_256 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv3_2', border_mode='same')(conv3_1_256)
conv3_3_256 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv3_3', border_mode='same')(conv3_2_256)
conv3_3_256 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv3_3_256)

conv4_1_512 = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv4_1', border_mode='same')(conv3_3_256)
conv4_2_512 = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv4_2', border_mode='same')(conv4_1_512)
conv4_3_512 = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv4_3', border_mode='same')(conv4_2_512)
conv4_3_512 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv4_3_512)

residual1 = BatchNormalization(axis=1, name='batch1')(conv4_3_512)
residual1 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='residual1', border_mode='same')(residual1)
residual1 = UpSampling2D(name='upsample1')(residual1)

conv3_3_256_batch_norm = BatchNormalization(axis=1, name='batch2')(conv3_3_256)
merge1 = merge((conv3_3_256_batch_norm, residual1), mode='concat', name='merge1', concat_axis=0)
residual2 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='residual2', border_mode='same')(merge1)
residual2 = UpSampling2D(name='upsample2')(residual2)

conv2_2_128_batch_norm = BatchNormalization(axis=1, name='batch3')(conv2_2_128)
merge2 = merge((conv2_2_128_batch_norm, residual2), mode='concat', name='merge2', concat_axis=0)
residual3 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='residual3', border_mode='same')(merge2)
residual3 = UpSampling2D(name='upsample3')(residual3)

conv1_2_64_batch_norm = BatchNormalization(axis=1, name='batch4')(conv1_2_64)
merge3 = merge((conv1_2_64_batch_norm, residual3), mode='concat', name='merge3', concat_axis=0)
residual4 = Convolution2D(3, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='residual4', border_mode='same')(merge3)
residual4 = UpSampling2D(name='upsample4')(residual4)

conv0_1_3_batch_norm = BatchNormalization(axis=1, name='batch5')(conv0_1_3)
merge4 = merge((conv0_1_3_batch_norm, residual4), mode='concat', name='merge4', concat_axis=0)
residual5 = Convolution2D(3, 1, 1, activation='relu', name='residual5', border_mode='same')(merge4)

model = Model(input=first_input, output=residual5)
```

and here's the Model Summary:

```
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)             (None, 1, 224, 224)   0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv0_1_3 (Convolution2D)        (None, 3, 224, 224)   30          input_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_1 (Convolution2D)          (None, 64, 224, 224)  1792        conv0_1_3[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_2 (Convolution2D)          (None, 64, 224, 224)  36928       conv1_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
maxpooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 64, 112, 112)  0           conv1_2[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2_1 (Convolution2D)          (None, 128, 112, 112) 73856       maxpooling2d_1[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2_2 (Convolution2D)          (None, 128, 112, 112) 147584      conv2_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
maxpooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 128, 56, 56)   0           conv2_2[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3_1 (Convolution2D)          (None, 256, 56, 56)   295168      maxpooling2d_2[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3_2 (Convolution2D)          (None, 256, 56, 56)   590080      conv3_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3_3 (Convolution2D)          (None, 256, 56, 56)   590080      conv3_2[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
maxpooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 256, 28, 28)   0           conv3_3[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv4_1 (Convolution2D)          (None, 512, 28, 28)   1180160     maxpooling2d_3[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv4_2 (Convolution2D)          (None, 512, 28, 28)   2359808     conv4_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv4_3 (Convolution2D)          (None, 512, 28, 28)   2359808     conv4_2[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
maxpooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 512, 14, 14)   0           conv4_3[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch1 (BatchNormalization)      (None, 512, 14, 14)   1024        maxpooling2d_4[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
residual1 (Convolution2D)        (None, 256, 14, 14)   1179904     batch1[0][0]                     
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch2 (BatchNormalization)      (None, 256, 28, 28)   512         maxpooling2d_3[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
upsample1 (UpSampling2D)         (None, 256, 28, 28)   0           residual1[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
merge1 (Merge)                   (None, 256, 28, 28)   0           batch2[0][0]                     
                                                                   upsample1[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
residual2 (Convolution2D)        (None, 128, 28, 28)   295040      merge1[0][0]                     
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch3 (BatchNormalization)      (None, 128, 56, 56)   256         maxpooling2d_2[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
upsample2 (UpSampling2D)         (None, 128, 56, 56)   0           residual2[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
merge2 (Merge)                   (None, 128, 56, 56)   0           batch3[0][0]                     
                                                                   upsample2[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
residual3 (Convolution2D)        (None, 64, 56, 56)    73792       merge2[0][0]                     
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch4 (BatchNormalization)      (None, 64, 112, 112)  128         maxpooling2d_1[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
upsample3 (UpSampling2D)         (None, 64, 112, 112)  0           residual3[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
merge3 (Merge)                   (None, 64, 112, 112)  0           batch4[0][0]                     
                                                                   upsample3[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
residual4 (Convolution2D)        (None, 3, 112, 112)   1731        merge3[0][0]                     
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch5 (BatchNormalization)      (None, 3, 224, 224)   6           conv0_1_3[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
upsample4 (UpSampling2D)         (None, 3, 224, 224)   0           residual4[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
merge4 (Merge)                   (None, 3, 224, 224)   0           batch5[0][0]                     
                                                                   upsample4[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
residual5 (Convolution2D)        (None, 3, 224, 224)   12          merge4[0][0]                     
====================================================================================================
Total params: 9187699
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong since the summary fits exactly with what I have in mind but no matter what, I keep getting this error :

> ValueError: GpuElemwise. Input dimension mis-match. Input 2 (indices start at 0) has shape[0] == 1, but the output's size on that axis is 5.
>   Apply node that caused the error: GpuElemwise{Composite{((i0 * (i1 + Abs(i1))) - i2)},no_inplace}(CudaNdarrayConstant{[[[[ 0.5]]]]}, GpuElemwise{Add}[(0, 0)].0, GpuFromHost.0)
>   Toposort index: 916
>   Inputs types: [CudaNdarrayType(float32, (True, True, True, True)), CudaNdarrayType(float32, 4D), CudaNdarrayType(float32, 4D)]
>   Inputs shapes: [(1, 1, 1, 1), (5, 3, 224, 224), (1, 3, 224, 224)]
>   Inputs strides: [(0, 0, 0, 0), (150528, 50176, 224, 1), (0, 50176, 224, 1)]
>   Inputs values: [CudaNdarray([[[[ 0.5]]]]), 'not shown', 'not shown']
>   Inputs type_num: ['', '', '']

I've included a Graph of the Model with this question too:
[image: model]

Debugging this is a nightmare... most of the other errors are pretty easy to understand and fix but these errors are really hard to understand... and unfortunately this isn't the first time I've had these errors with Keras.

Please! what is wrong with this model?! am I doing something completely wrong or perhaps this model shouldn't be designed this way?

Thanks so much...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are merging on the wrong axis. `axis = 0` is actually the axis with different samples. You can see from your model:

```
batch2 (BatchNormalization)      (None, 256, 28, 28)   512         maxpooling2d_3[0][0]             
upsample1 (UpSampling2D)         (None, 256, 28, 28)   0           residual1[0][0]                  
merge1 (Merge)                   (None, 256, 28, 28)   0           batch2[0][0]
```

The number of feature maps is not changing at all after the merge. Set `axis = 1` to fix this.

Comment: Thanks so much... You're a life saver! This took a day of my life!